# error: nothing provides perl(NKF) needed by w3m-0.5.3-60.git20230121.el8.x86_64

Tags: perl, w3m

I tried to install w3m on a redhat 8 system and got the error.

```
# yum install w3m.x86_64
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
misc                                             53 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00
chop_vmware                                      44 kB/s | 2.0 kB     00:00
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(NKF) needed by w3m-0.5.3-60.git20230121.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
# uname -a
Linux reslndbhisbox05.research.chop.edu 4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 14 16:00:01 EST 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Trying --skip-broken or --nobest as suggested didn't fix the problem.  I appreciate any help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The w3m rpm needs an rpm that provides "perl(NFK)". This is a virtual provide automatically generated by any rpm that ships a NFK perl module.

Looking at https://pkgs.org/, it looks like this is provided by the perl-NFK rpm found in the Powertools repository. Perhaps this repository is not enabled on your system and that is why dnf cannot find the package.